# Contrasting the different ways of adding an existing framework to Xcode

Tags: xcode

In Xcode (specifically v3.2.4), there are two ways of adding an external framework to a solution

1. Dragging and dropping a framework from finding into XCode
2. Clicking on add existing, and selecting one

Surprisingly, the two ways do not yield the same result (I learned this the hard way). Here is a diff of the two methods on the contents of project.pbxproj in the .xcodeproj package:

**By dragging**
005DB04C1255606C005A66F1 /* GHUnitIOS.framework */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = wrapper.framework; path = GHUnitIOS.framework; sourceTree = ""; };

**By adding existing**
005DB06C12556222005A66F1 /* GHUnitIOS.framework */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = wrapper.framework; name = GHUnitIOS.framework; path = Library/Frameworks/GHUnitIOS.framework; sourceTree = DEVELOPER_DIR; };

A different value for the **path** and a different one for the **source tree** is produced.

Does anyone know what these differences are, and what the advantage of each method is?

Comment: You can use two ways for 'add existing', by selecting 'existing framework' or 'existing file', and... yes, it yields different results too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are just different defaults for how the path to the framework is defined. You can change these by doing a "Get Info" on the framework and setting the "Path Type" popup in the "General" tab accordingly.